# Object detection from multiple sources

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have initiated a single object detection model using the coco ssd.
I am trying to detect objects from 2 different cameras

THE LOGIC OF THE CODE:-

```
model=cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
cam1=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam1=cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#thread 1
while true:
    success1,img1 = cam1.read()
    result1=model.detect(img1)
    cv2.imshow("result1", result1)
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF==ord('x'):
        break

#thread 2 
while true:
    success2,img2 = cam2.read()
    result2=model.detect(img2)
    cv2.imshow("result2", result2)
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF==ord('x'):
        break
```

using this approach in neither of the video frames the correct objects are detected
[image: OUTPUT]
The above image shows the output i am getting.
with a single thread it works fine but if i try running more than one thread then it starts producing such errors for all video sources.
why is this happening???
what might be the solution?

Comment: Can you share a minimal example that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Depending how your actual code handles race conditions, you should try using two separate instances of your model, one for each thread. Something like:

```
model1=cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
model2=cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
```

Comment: Actually the number of threads are not defined. The threads are created dynamically. so for each thread i can't create an individual model.
Is there any other way around?

Comment: This really depends on the details. Can you share your actual code instead of just a sketch of the logic?